# Count number of rows in a column compared to system date ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table with a column called due_date that defines when a tool is due. I need to compare this value to the system date (sysdate) and count how many rows fill certain conditions.

I need to:

Count the number of rows with tools that are DUE (due_date > sysdate) ex- "tools_due" with 50 rows

Count the number of rows of tools that are NOT DUE (due_date < sysdate) ex- "tools_not" with 20 rows

and

Count the number of rows that are DUE TODAY (due_date = sysdate) ex- "tools_today" with 10 rows

THEN I need to take each count, compare, and store the condition with the highest row count. ex- 
"highest_count"

So in this example, tools_due returned with 50 rows, being the highest of the 3, so "high_count" would equal 50 or "tools_due".

How would I be able to do this? I've tried using a case inside the count clauses but I'm certain I'm not using it correctly.

EDIT- Forgot to mention that my output HAS to output at least one of strings I put in those DBMS lines in the screenshot. My bad my bad.

Here's what I have so far: 
[my doodoocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XIIp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exhibit the case (not due, due, due today) that has the highest count, it is easier to process rows than columns. You can use `UNION ALL` to generate records for each of the three cases, and then order the rows by count and return only record with the greatest count:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 'due' reason, COUNT(*) cnt FROM mytable WHERE TRUNC(due_date) > TRUNC(sysdate)
        UNION ALL SELECT 'not due', COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TRUNC(due_date) < TRUNC(sysdate)
        UNION ALL SELECT 'due today', COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE TRUNC(due_date) = TRUNC(sysdate)
    ) 
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0383858209ba50d7348d1208e376656d)**

Set-up:

```
| DUE_DATE            |
| :------------------ |
| 2019-10-10 22:10:43 |
| 2019-10-11 22:10:43 |
| 2019-10-12 22:10:43 |
| 2019-10-13 22:10:43 |
```

Results:

```
REASON  | CNT
:------ | --:
not due |   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want logic like this:

```
select sum(case when trunc(due_date) > trunc(sysdate + 1) then 1 else  0 end) as due_later,
       sum(case when trunc(due_date) = trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as due_today,
       sum(case when trunc(due_date) < trunc(sysdate) then 1 else 0 end) as due_earlier
from . . .
```

In Oracle `sysdate` has a time component and that might be throwing you off.  Also, the `date` data type has a time component, which you might not see when looking at the value.

Comment: Is there any reason why SUM would be better than COUNT in this case? I saw the same thing in some other posts, but didn't really see anyone's logic behind it.

Comment: Count will give you else part results as well so either remove else or use sum()

Comment: @Hoodie . . . Are you asking why I prefer `sum()`?  The reason is that `count(1) = count(2)` and I find that a bit counterintuitive.  When using `sum()` what the code is doing is quite clear:  `sum(1) <> sum(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

As date type has time embeded in it in Oracle hence use trunc on both sides when comparing dates to truncate the time part

```
    Trunc(column) = trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` as following:

```
Select max(count(1)) from
(Select case when diff = 0 
             then 'due today'
             When diff < 0 then 'due'
             Else 'not due' end as status
 From
(Select trunc(due_date) - trunc(sysdate) as diff,
        Due_date 
  from your table))
Group by status;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRUNC( due_date )` will prevent Oracle from using an index on the `due_date` 
column (you would need a function-based index instead). An alternative would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN due_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
         THEN due_date
         END
       ) AS tools_not_due_yet,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN due_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
         AND  due_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
         THEN due_date
         END
       ) AS tools_due_today,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN due_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
         THEN due_date
         END
       ) AS tools_overdue
FROM   your_table
```